# How to use nlmer from lme4 with non-Normal data

Tags: lme4, gamma

I am testing some non-linear models with `nlmer` from the `lme4` library. But this function assumes normality while my data clearly follows a Gamma distribution.

```
fit <- lme4::nlmer(y ~ nfun(x, b0, b1, b2) ~
                 (b0|id),
             data = df,
             start = start.df, REML=T)
summary(fit)
```

Is there a way of adding a family group, as for `lme4`, or any other tips for testing groups within non-linear models when data is not Gaussian?

Answer (score 1):

The options for fitting non-linear generalized mixed models in (pure) R are slim to nonexistent.

- the `brms` package offers some scope for nonlinear fitting
- you can build a nonlinear model in `TMB` (but you have to do your own programming in an extension of C++)
- other front-end packages like `rethinking`, `greta`, `rjags`, etc. also allow you to build nonlinear mixed effects models — but all (?) in a Bayesian/MCMC framework

On the other hand, Gamma-based models can often be adequately substituted by log-Normal-based models (i.e. `log(y) ~ nfun(x, b0, b1, b2)`); while the tail shapes of these distributions are very different, the variance-mean relationship for the standard parameterizations is the same, and the results of a (log-link) Gamma GLMM and the corresponding log-Gaussian model are often very similar.

Or you could use a fixed effect for the groups (if you have enough data) and use `bbmle::mle2` with the `params` argument.